# Add symbol with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to add an `-` after each 4 characters:

Example:

`498c665baf79ad6e` -> `498c-665b-af79-ad6e`

Comment: Do you have a string? or an array? What do you have that you want to add dashes to?

Comment: how is your input, can you give example

Comment: I'm using  variable with `md5()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
echo implode('-', str_split('498c665baf79ad6e', 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$source = "...";

$hypenated = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($source)/4; $i++) {
    $hypenated[] = substr($source, $i*4, 4);
}

$hypenated = implode('-', $hypenated);
```

Comment: i think there is *typo* ,this must be `$hypenated= "-"`, m i right??

Comment: You forgot to add the hyphen at the end of the substr ;) `$hyphenated .= substr(...) . '-';` And, after the `for` loop: `$hyphenated = substr($hyphenated, 0, -1);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = '498c665baf79ad6e';
echo preg_replace ('/(.{4})(?=.)/', '\1-', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
<?php
echo rtrim(chunk_split('498c665baf79ad6e', 4, '-'), '-');
```